# Match multiple expressions in different lines with a logical AND using grep - all expressions must occur in the same textfile

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I tried to return all python-scripts (textfiles) which contained both `main()` and `plt.style.use` **somewhere** within the file, i.e. not in the same line.

I found some documentations like [this](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/10/grep-or-and-not-operators/) explaining how to use logical operators with `grep` on single lines in textfiles, but nothing was mentioned regarding entire textfiles.

What I tried out was the following:

```
grep -Rinw /home/andylu/Desktop/Python/Scripts/ -e 'main()\|plt.style.use'
```

This command returned all textfiles which contained any of the terms like a logical OR.

As a logical AND doesn't exist with `grep`, one could match any order per line of the multiple expressions as mentioned in [the example](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/10/grep-or-and-not-operators/):

> grep -E 'Manager.*Sales|Sales.*Manager' employee.txt

This wouldn't help me either, because the terms I'm looking for are coded in different lines within the python-scripts, but must occur both in the same textfile to be relevant for me. These are the textfiles I would like to filter out and return in the console via `grep`, or whatever alternative tools.

---

**OS:** Lubuntu 20.04 LTS